# Failed review audit : missing information to correctly review

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed this review https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17779999 and I must admit I don't understand why the answer, as shown in the review, is that bad.

[image: Screenshot of the answer]

I guess that the answerer posted one too many answer with that link and it got nuked by Brad Larson, but I'm afraid a reviewer can't know that. What should have I done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's spam. The username and the site he links to are the same.

Users can link to their own blogs, [but only as a supplement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/how-to-refer-to-your-blog-when-answering).
In this case, 80% of the answer is in the blog.

Comment: Really? You shouldn't have a username that matches your blog name/company/whatever? That seems a bit harsh

Comment: No, that's okay, but you have to be very transparent about the fact it's _your_ blog.